# What does this phrase: "The vestal vamp" means in this context?

Tags: meaning

I came across this NY Times headline:

> ["Olivia Newton-John: That Headband Was a Crown](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/08/09/arts/music/olivia-newton-john-grease-physical.html#:%7E:text=When%20the%20singer%20smudged%20her,%3A%20%E2%80%9CThe%20vestal%20vamp.%E2%80%9D&text=As%20a%20subscriber%2C%20you%20have,can%20read%20what%20you%20share.)
>
> When the singer smudged her classy image, she “unlocked something new that shot her to the top of pop’s Olympus,” our critic writes: “The vestal vamp.”"

what is meant by "The vestal vamp"???

Comment: Are you aware of the meanings of "vestal" and "vamp" ?

Comment: @JamesK - they are conveniently near to each other in the dictionary, which may go some way to explaining the NYT headline.

Comment: Certainly Wesley Morris was proud of his alliteration

Answer (score 1):

This is an *oxymoron* a combination of two words of opposite meaning. Used rhetorically to reveal a paradox.

*Vestal* refers to the Vestal Virgins of Rome, who were chaste and pure beyond suspicion.  And *Vamp* is a woman who uses her sex appeal and charm to exploit men.

So the oxymoron reveals a paradox in the persona of Olivia Newton-John.

Comment: thanks. oxymoron are interesting. I will be trying to use them

Comment: I can honestly  say that I never saw any vamp side to her, even after sitting all the way through 'Xanadu'. Maybe it was because of the roller skates. She was considered a 'soulmate' by Cliff Richard, which is not terribly vampish. I would say she was an icon in the same way as Judy Garland, Kylie Minogue, etc.

Comment: Oxymorons are not specifically English.  They can be used in any language.

Comment: I just watched a clip from Xanadu of her singing that song, and I am filling up!

Comment: This is clearly the sense in the article: Morris writes about the “virginal bobby-soxer” who is transformed into wearing skintight black pants